# VPN To a Specific Docker Network

Tags: iptables, docker, vpn, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

My goal is to find a solution that would alow me to host specific ports and services publically on a VPS while having other administrative UI's that might interact with said public services buttoned down.

So far, my solution has been to bind my exposed docker ports to the host local loopback address and use SSH tunnels to connect back to them. This has *worked* though I might soon be running into port conflicts (and my ssh command is getting extensevely longer).

I'd like to create an isolated Docker network where I can utilize a split-tunnel VPN to connect to alot of administrative UI's all the while use a reverse proxy to direct public traffic to specific docker ports. Idealy I'd like to use Wiregaurd inside a docker container and utilize something like Wireguard-UI or Firezone to help facilitate client configurations.

Here's an example diagram of the intended use:
[image]

What's making this all kinds of complicated is how Docker interacts with iptables. If anyone has a general step guide that might accomplish this, please let me know.

I've also considered some alternatives like Authelia but I'd rather not allow the configuration interfaces to be accessible at all over the plain net if I could help it.

Comment: I don't think there are any particular issues here caused by Docker's firewall rules. Just run wireguard in a container, publish the appropriate ports, and you should be all set. There are already wireguard container images available to get you started (e.g. [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/wireguard)).

Comment: Instead of running a VPN container which iptables can complicate things, how about installing OpenVPN daemon on the VPS itself. The VPS will run docker engine, VPN server, and possibly nginx reverse proxy. When a client connects to VPN, the connection will be terminated at the VPS and client will have full access to any port to any docker container. Whereas direct connections from internet will be governed by nginx

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi I think you're right. Installing the VPN Server directly on the host would eleviate any pain points of Docker's own iptable chain. It would also allow me to better apply firewall rules around it from the hosts' network stack.

I'm a bit hesitant to mess with the host network since I already managed to block myself out of the VPS resulting in a re-deployment alteast once. I'd also like to configure something with a UI for managing VPN connection profiles and there's quite a few docker images that accomplish that. 

I'll give it a shot and see if I don't lock myself out again.

Comment: @larsks That image looks simple enough to use. I'd prefer one with a UI for easy profile creation and sharing though not neccisary. Part of the problem with alot of the UI related docker projects are that there's quite a few that ask for a network interface to bind to and I'm not sure if it's referencing the internal interface that the docker containers use or the external interfaces that are on the host. 

Think I might opt for installing the VPN on the host directly and then configure it to tap into different docker networks depending on profile. Thanks for the referenced image though.

Comment: @BobserLuck You can install "OpenVPN Access Server" on your host machine if GUI is a prefered method to manage VPN users. OpenVPN Access Server free version will allow 2 concurrent VPN sessions. Since you are the only one at a time, this solution will be suitable.

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi Thanks for the suggestion. Though the limited number of allowed connections is why I tend to steer clear of OpenVPN. I try to build around Free (Libre) software when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a working solution. Apparently UFW also likes to get in the way when routing between different networks.

Solution:

1. Install WireGuard on the VPS directly and configure it with [wiregaurd-ui](https://github.com/ngoduykhanh/wireguard-ui), adding an extra environment variable to bind to the VPS' localhost (ssh to forward the port back to my own machine. I don't plan on having it run very often).
2. Configure the client with the appropriate "allowed IP" field of the folowing docker network subnet.
3. Create a new docker network and spin up a [Network-Multitool](https://github.com/wbitt/Network-MultiTool) container attached to the network. Binding no ports to the host. Comes with a built in Apache server and tons of network testing tools.
4. Make sure ipv4 forwarding is enabled for the [VPS](https://linuxhint.com/enable_ip_forwarding_ipv4_debian_linux/) and [UFW](https://securitynetworkinglinux.wordpress.com/2019/07/03/how-to-port-forward-ipv4-traffic-using-ufw-on-ubuntu-cli/) (restart the VPS after enabled).
5. Set UFW rule to allow port forwarding `ufw route allow in on <wg0> out on <docker bridge interface>` and reloading ufw.
6. exec into the Multitool container and spin up tcpdump port 80. Start the wireguard interface on my local machine and curl to the containers internal IP address to verify connectivity.